# cell background color not changing javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a heatmap for some results I have based on some simple thresholds. I'm using JavaScript to create, set up the value and the background color. The expected result is a heatmap using some `blue` different tonalities. However, nothing is being colored, and by analysing the DOM I found:

```
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
```

Thus, the `bgcolor="#"` is not setup. I have used both `bgcolor` and `setAtribute`, but the result it is the same: nothing is being colored. My function is posted below:

```
function makeTable(data)
    {
        var row = new Array();
        var cell = new Array();

        var row_num = 26;
        var cell_num = 44;

        var tab = document.createElement('table');
        tab.setAttribute('id', 'newtable');
        tab.border = '1px';

        var tbo = document.createElement('tbody');

        for(var i = 0; i < row_num; i++){
            row[i] = document.createElement('tr');

            var upper = (i+1)*44;
            var lower = i*44;
            for(var j = lower; j < upper; j++){
                cell[j] = document.createElement('td');
                if(data[j] != undefined){
                    var index = document.createTextNode(data[j].diff);
                    cell[j].appendChild(index);
                    /* specify which color better suits the heatmap */
                    if(index >= 0 || index <= 100){
                        cell[j].bgcolor = "#ADDDE6";
                    }
                    else if(index > 100 || index <= 1000){
                        cell[j].bgcolor = "#00BFFF";
                    }
                    else if(index > 1000 || index <= 4000){
                        cell[j].bgcolor = "#6495ED";
                    }
                    else if(index > 4000 || index <= 6000){
                        cell[j].bgcolor = "#00008B";
                    }
                    else{
                        cell[j].bgcolor = "#0000FF";
                    }
                    row[i].appendChild(cell[j]);
                }
            }

            tbo.appendChild(row[i]);
        }

        tab.appendChild(tbo);
        document.getElementById('mytable').appendChild(tab);
    }
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.style.backgroundColor="red"
```

Comment: I changed to `cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "red";` however I had the same outcome: nothing being colored.

Comment: also use built in table functions ie. table.insertRow(-1) and row.insertCell(-1)... its less expensive then create and appending.. and makes for shorter code

Answer (score 0):

You need a capitalized C in bgcolor property -> bgColor.